# Angular loadChildren route fails randomly, defaults to wildcard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a route that a user enters from an email and the first time they hit the app, it has about a 90% chance for them to be redirected to the wildcard catch rather than the specific route they are supposed to hit.

If they refresh, or come to the site via the same link again, there is a good chance they will go to the component that is supposed to load. I would like the route to load every time, not sure if loadChildren is running too slow occasionally or if the router just barfs randomly. Here is the routing:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: 'LoginModule', // assume this is correct
        data: { routeIndex: 1 }
    },
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login/head' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login/head' }
];
```

The login module has routes that match the following

```
export const LOGIN_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'first-page',
        component: FirstPageComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'somewhereelse',
                component: BlahBlahComponent,
                data: { routeIndex: 0 }
            }
        ]
    },
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login/head' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login/head' }
]
```

The route they are sent to is: *"/login/first-page"* but instead they are getting sent to *"/login/head"* on the first load of the app.

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening and how to fix it?

I should also note this only seems to happen when it's deployed on a server, not running localhost. It always goes where it's supposed to locally as far as my testing has gone

Answer (score 0):

This is how you lazy load the route in angular 8

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(mod => mod.CustomersModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(mod => mod.OrdersModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

And for previous version

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'lazymodule', loadChildren: './lazymodule/lazymodule.module#LazyModuleModule' }
];
```

You need to add correct path to the module you want to lazy load

Update try to update your routing like this to see if it work

```
export const LOGIN_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'first-page',
        component: FirstPageComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'somewhereelse',
                component: BlahBlahComponent,
                data: { routeIndex: 0 }
            }
        ]
    },
    { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login/head' }
]
```

Comment: I'm using the correct method (the second one you posted). The problem isn't that they don't load, it's that they don't load the first time a new user hits the site.

Comment: Just update my answer you have problem because you have 2 route that using same `''`

Comment: Don't routes use the first available route in the list? This is how my more specific routes work over the generic '' route. I want the user to hit 'first-page'. If I reverse the order of the routes, it goes to the wrong spot every time (just tried it).

Comment: Just update my answer. I think you can try with 2 ways I just provided

Comment: I unfortunately can't put it as a child route of "LoginComponent" because I have logic in there that I don't need. The "FirstPageComponent" is a parent level component that needs to be on top

Comment: No unfortunately

Comment: After more testing, I found that it is going to the wildcard route as if the main route was "bad". It's the same as if I entered a bad route like "first-paggeee333", it will go to "login/head"